# Does the reduction of order yield the general solution of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a ODE of order 2,  $$c_0(x) y''+c_1(x) y'+ c_2(x) y=q(x)$$ if we somehow find a solution $h(x)$ for homogeneous equation, then we can reduce the order of the non-homogeneous equation by letting $y(x)=h(x)z(x)$.

Then by letting $u(x)=z'(x)$, we have a first order equation. If we find the general solution $u(x)$ for this first equation, integrate it and get $z(x) $.

Is $y(x)$ the general solution for the original equation?